# How do I fix php7.1-fpm.sock failure on Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, php-7.1

I am trying to solve my white screen problem. Currently, I'm unable to login to one of my staging servers. I'm running Laravel 5.2 / php 7.1-fpm. After doing a repository update(via [Forge](https://forge.laravel.com/)), I hit the white screen view.

Based on my domain error log, I think that fixing the `php7.1-fpm.sock` failure will solve my white screen error.

I've tried just about every suggestion from various forums; I've tried suggestions from several similar related stack-overflow threads.

I still haven't found a solution. Can anyone offer suggestions?

Below is the error.log  contents:

> 2018/08/12 21:16:09 [crit] 949#949: *28 SSL_do_handshake() failed
>   (SSL: error:1417D102:SSL routines:tls_process_client_hello:unsupported
>   protocol) while SSL handshaking, client: 23.27.154.95, server:
>   0.0.0.0:443
>   2018/08/13 00:43:46 [crit] 949#949: *47 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:1417D102:SSL
>
> routines:tls_process_client_hello:unsupported protocol) while SSL
>   handshaking, client: 220.181.132.198, server: 0.0.0.0:443
>
> 2018/08/13 00:43:46 [crit] 949#949: *48 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL:
>   error:1417D18C:SSL routines:tls_process_client_hello:version too low)
>   while SSL handshaking, client: 220.181.132.198, server: 0.0.0.0:443
>
> 2018/08/13 00:43:47 [crit] 949#949: *49 SSL_do_handshake() failed
>   (SSL: error:1417D102:SSL routines:tls_process_client_hello:unsupported
>   protocol) while SSL handshaking, client: 220.181.132.198, server:
>   0.0.0.0:443

Below is my site's error log contents:

> 2018/08/11 17:48:31 [crit] 934#934: *1 connect() to
>   unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or
>   directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 73.106.222.129,
>   server: blabs.goteachersintouch.com, request: "GET / HTTP/2.0",
>   upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock:", host:
>   "blabs.goteachersintouch.com"
>
> 2018/08/11 17:48:35 [crit] 1266#1266: *1 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file
>   or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 73.106.222.129,
>   server: blabs.goteachersintouch.com, request: "GET /img/body-bg.png
>   HTTP/2.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock:",
>   host: "blabs.goteachersintouch.com", referrer:
>   "https://blabs.goteachersintouch.com/build/css/app-5aaeb8644f.css"

Before I did the Repository Uninstall with Laravel Forge, my build was working fine. Apparently setting my server to it's original PHP state is not in alignment with some configuration (there's something I'm missing, I just can't see it).

My codebase is still running on Laravel 5.2 library. But even still, can anyone offer suggestions to fix this white screen issue.

I have tried the permissions adjustments--that hasn't worked.

Thank you!

Comment: `tls_process_client_hello:version too low` that'd be where I would start looking.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was missing a bower file. The file was angular-sanitize#1.6.1
I ran:"bower install angular-sanitize#1.6.1" and was up and running again.